# MAMP set up under the administrator account does not start servers under user account

Tags: macos, mac, mysql, mamp

I set up MAMP under an administrator account on this Mac OS 10.6.6.  That works fine.  The Apache and MySQL server start and php works. When I log on to a user account with administrator privileges and start MAMP, the Apache and MySQL server don't start. That user account has administrator privileges but does not have a password.

Here is the error message.

> /Applications/MAMP/LIbrary/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't
> connect to local MySQL server through socket
> '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.dock'(61) when tyring to connect.

That user account has administrator privileges but does not have a password.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try some permissions adjustments, per [this post](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7049):

> The answer is just go to the `/Applications/MAMP/` folder and add the
>   desired user(s), with reading and writing permissions, on the "Get
>   info" (<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>) inspector for that folder.

An alternate solution might be to launch MAMP silently at system startup. Details listed on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7326744). Additional info located at [this page](http://stringfoo.com/2008/08/25/tutorial-launching-mamp-silently-on-startup/).